# Could not import maven project into IntelliJ, Unrecognized option: -d64

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

Today I tried to import a project into IntelliJ

But IntelliJ fails with error

```
2019-11-19 14:00:46,104 [ 385724]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - IntelliJ IDEA 2018.2.6  Build #IU-182.5107.16 
2019-11-19 14:00:46,104 [ 385724]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - JDK: 1.8.0_152-release 
2019-11-19 14:00:46,104 [ 385724]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 
2019-11-19 14:00:46,104 [ 385724]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Vendor: JetBrains s.r.o 
2019-11-19 14:00:46,104 [ 385724]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - OS: Mac OS X 
2019-11-19 14:00:46,104 [ 385724]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Last Action: ShowProjectStructureSettings 
2019-11-19 14:00:46,322 [ 385942]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - Unrecognized option: -d64 
2019-11-19 14:00:46,322 [ 385942]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine. 
2019-11-19 14:00:46,322 [ 385942]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit. 
2019-11-19 14:00:46,350 [ 385970]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - Unrecognized option: -d64 
2019-11-19 14:00:46,350 [ 385970]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine. 
2019-11-19 14:00:46,350 [ 385970]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit. 
2019-11-19 14:00:46,350 [ 385970]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Cannot reconnect. 
java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot reconnect.
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.RemoteObjectWrapper.perform(RemoteObjectWrapper.java:82)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.MavenServerManager.applyProfiles(MavenServerManager.java:526)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProjectReader.applyProfiles(MavenProjectReader.java:394)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProjectReader.doReadProjectModel(MavenProjectReader.java:103)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProjectReader.readProject(MavenProjectReader.java:62)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProject.read(MavenProject.java:655)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.wizards.MavenProjectBuilder.collectProfiles(MavenProjectBuilder.java:198)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.wizards.MavenProjectBuilder.access$900(MavenProjectBuilder.java:35)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.wizards.MavenProjectBuilder$1.run(MavenProjectBuilder.java:172)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.utils.MavenUtil$1.run(MavenUtil.java:419)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:736)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$5.run(CoreProgressManager.java:434)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$1(CoreProgressManager.java:157)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:580)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:525)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:85)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:144)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.lambda$null$10(ApplicationImpl.java:574)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:314)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.rmi.RemoteException: Cannot start maven service; nested exception is: 
    com.intellij.execution.ExecutionException: Unrecognized option: -d64
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.

    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.MavenServerManager.create(MavenServerManager.java:161)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.MavenServerManager.create(MavenServerManager.java:66)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.RemoteObjectWrapper.getOrCreateWrappee(RemoteObjectWrapper.java:41)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.MavenServerManager.lambda$applyProfiles$3(MavenServerManager.java:526)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.RemoteObjectWrapper.perform(RemoteObjectWrapper.java:76)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: com.intellij.execution.ExecutionException: Unrecognized option: -d64
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.

    at com.intellij.execution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport.acquire(RemoteProcessSupport.java:159)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.MavenServerManager.create(MavenServerManager.java:158)
    ... 27 more
2019-11-19 14:00:46,351 [ 385971]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - IntelliJ IDEA 2018.2.6  Build #IU-182.5107.16 
2019-11-19 14:00:46,351 [ 385971]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - JDK: 1.8.0_152-release 
2019-11-19 14:00:46,351 [ 385971]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 
2019-11-19 14:00:46,351 [ 385971]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Vendor: JetBrains s.r.o 
2019-11-19 14:00:46,351 [ 385971]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - OS: Mac OS X 
2019-11-19 14:00:46,351 [ 385971]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Last Action: ShowProjectStructureSettings
```

What is "Unrecognized option: -d64", where is -d64 come from ?

Comment: Are you trying to run a 32 Bit version on your mac ?

Comment: What JDK do you use to run Maven? Preferences -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Maven -> Importing. Does it help if you set it to 1.8?

Comment: I'm running on 64 Bit, @khmarbaise

Comment: I have to use Java 11 @CrazyCoder

Comment: You will need to update to a more recent IntelliJ IDEA version: http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/index.html.

Answer (score 0):

I completely uninstall my IntelliJ, and re-installed it. After re-install, it fixed